# Converting fat arrow to standard notation

Tags: javascript

How do I convert this piece of code to *not* use the fat arrow?

```
propertyOf = object => {
  return propName => {
    for (let key in object) {
  if(key === propName) return object[key]
    }
  }
}
```

I changed the first line to

```
propertyOf = function (object) {
```

and the code still worked. When I changed also the second line to

```
return propName = function () {
```

I got an error saying "undefined" when I tried to call the function. I also got an error beside the second line saying 'Did you mean to run a conditional instead of an assignment?'

The full code is this:

```
let bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 87
},
searchBob;

propertyOf = object => {
  return propName => {
    for (let key in object) {
  if(key === propName) return object[key]
    }
  }
}

searchBob = propertyOf(bob);



console.log(searchBob('age'));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the `return propName => {`, propName is the parameter of the function, so it translates to

```
return function(propName) {
```

In the [documentation of the arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), it is specified that when there is only one parameter, the parenthesis can be omitted.

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out that the snippet you've tried to use

```
return propName = function () {
```

is  *valid* JavaScript. You get `undefined` because `propName` variable is undefined inside your inner function. Hence the `if` condition in the `for..in` loop pretty much translates to

```
if (key === undefined) // This never passes, hence undefined is returned
```

Your code will *work* if you change it to

```
return propName = function(propName) {
```

Full working example:

```js
let bob = {
    name: 'Bob',
    age: 87
  },
  searchBob;

propertyOf = function(object) {
  return propName = function(/* This is the only change */ propName) {
    for (let key in object) {
      if (key === propName) return object[key]
    }
  }
}

searchBob = propertyOf(bob);

console.log(searchBob('age'));
```

That being said, I don't see any reason why you should be doing it. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44961526/2950032) is the most simple one.

Answer (score 1):

I will do it this way:

```
let bob = {
  name: 'Bob',
  age: 87
},
searchBob;

propertyOf = function (person,propName) {

    for (let key in person) {
       if(key === propName) return person[key]
    }

}

searchBob = propertyOf(bob, "name");
```